# Could someone recommend a good book on designing web UI with css?

Tags: css, user-interface

Not javascript related,but only with pure css.

I really need a book to teach me how to beautify the web UI badly!

Comment: Added the tag 'skills-development' since I think that's the heart of your question. Feel free to un-tag if you disagree =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out "Stylin with CSS". Its the best book on CSS in my opinion. Very well written, easy to understand. try it out.

Answer (score 3):

I own [The Zen of CSS Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321303474), a **great** book:

http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41oIY8vq5uL.jpg

Comment: I've read this book before,but seems an older version.When is this versino released?

Answer (score 2):

- Dan Cederholm's [Bulletproof Web Design](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Bulletproof-Web-Design-Flexibility-Protecting/dp/0321509021);
- The follow-up, by Cederholm and Ethan Marcotte, [Handcrafted CSS: More bulletproof Web Design](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Handcrafted-CSS-More-Bulletproof-Design/dp/0321658531);
- Eric Meyer's [More Eric Meyer on CSS](http://www.amazon.co.uk/More-Eric-Meyer-Voices-Matter/dp/0735714258);
- Dave Shea and Molly Holzschlag's [The ZEN of CSS Design: Visual Enlightenment for the Web (Voices That Matter)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/ZEN-CSS-Design-Visual-Enlightenment/dp/0321303474).
- Also, any of the books recommended in this topic "[What is the best book on css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199486/what-is-the-best-book-on-css)."

Comment: this answer is better and more complete than mine, +1

Answer (score 1):

[Bulletproof Web Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321509021)

[CSS Mastery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223979)

Answer (score 0):

[Bulletproof Web Design](http://simplebits.com/publications/bulletproof/) - Dan Cedarholm

Answer (score 0):

http://www.csszengarden.com/ has a ton of sample sites showing off the capabilities of CSS.
Each site uses the same HTML structure, and just changes the CSS to change the design.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out some online resources. I know you specifically asked for book recommendations, but these will get you up & running too.

1. http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/
2. http://www.tizag.com/cssT/
3. http://www.cssdog.com/css_intro.html
4. http://www.smashapps.org/2009/07/css-tutorials-for-beginners.html

Skills Development is great - good luck!!